# Slow request - mysql server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

Sometimes the server needs a lot of time for a request. There's also an error that there are too many connections to the mysql server.

I've set the max_connections up to 800 but this doesn't help at all. I've also optimized the database.

Here's a top output when the problem is present.

```
top - 20:07:48 up 164 days, 13:21,  1 user,  load average: 10.70, 12.08, 11.45
Tasks: 186 total,   8 running, 178 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 34.6%us,  6.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  2.0%id, 56.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6291456k total,  1200580k used,  5090876k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
13780 mysql     15   0  122m  70m 4876 S    6  1.2  53:54.73 mysqld             
 3269 www-data  16   0 49792  26m 3988 S    4  0.4   0:00.36 apache2            
 3386 www-data  15   0 48016  24m 4032 S    4  0.4   0:00.35 apache2            
 3385 www-data  16   0 48020  24m 3920 S    3  0.4   0:00.21 apache2            
 3394 www-data  15   0 48048  24m 3924 S    3  0.4   0:00.20 apache2            
 3417 www-data  16   0 47984  24m 3960 S    3  0.4   0:00.30 apache2            
 3226 www-data  15   0 49012  26m 4200 S    3  0.4   0:00.36 apache2            
 3094 www-data  15   0 48040  24m 4100 S    3  0.4   0:01.33 apache2            
 3170 www-data  16   0 48028  25m 4180 S    3  0.4   0:00.45 apache2            
 3192 www-data  15   0 48252  25m 4036 S    3  0.4   0:00.48 apache2            
 3342 www-data  15   0 47980  24m 4000 S    3  0.4   0:00.36 apache2            
 3435 www-data  16   0 49008  25m 3844 S    3  0.4   0:00.20 apache2            
 1242 www-data  16   0 48048  24m 4132 S    2  0.4   0:00.72 apache2            
 1562 www-data  15   0 50136  27m 4620 S    2  0.4   0:01.66 apache2            
 3166 www-data  15   0 47980  24m 4012 S    2  0.4   0:00.52 apache2            
 3169 www-data  16   0 45596  23m 4256 R    2  0.4   0:01.29 apache2            
 3393 www-data  16   0 45580  22m 4012 R    2  0.4   0:00.21 apache2
```

What data would also help to identify the problem?

Here's the output from mysql:

```
mysql> show variables like '%cache%';
+------------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name                | Value      |
+------------------------------+------------+
| binlog_cache_size            | 32768      | 
| have_query_cache             | YES        | 
| key_cache_age_threshold      | 300        | 
| key_cache_block_size         | 1024       | 
| key_cache_division_limit     | 100        | 
| max_binlog_cache_size        | 4294967295 | 
| ndb_cache_check_time         | 0          | 
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576    | 
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096       | 
| query_cache_size             | 16777216   | 
| query_cache_type             | ON         | 
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF        | 
| table_cache                  | 64         | 
| thread_cache_size            | 8          | 
+------------------------------+------------+
```

I'll post an output of free and sar when the problem appears again.

---

According to mysql tuning primer all config vars are OK now, however the wait rate is still quite high. Do you have any hints how to find out what causes the high I/O traffic?

Here's the output of top again:

```
top - 16:26:32 up 172 days,  9:40,  1 user,  load average: 5.29, 4.52, 3.45
Tasks:  35 total,   1 running,  34 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.5%us,  2.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 97.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6291456k total,   122712k used,  6168744k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            

14118 mysql     15   0  109m  20m 4520 S    3  0.3   0:01.32 mysqld             
 1244 root      16   0 35224  19m 3856 D    2  0.3 204:41.52 apache2            
    1 root      15   0  1960  688  584 S    0  0.0   0:11.83 init               
 1041 root      15   0  5216  996  640 S    0  0.0   6:13.44 sshd               
1064 root      15   0  2328  824  660 S    0  0.0   0:35.44 xinetd             
1132 root      15   0 31292  28m 2344 S    0  0.5   0:55.09 spamd              
1166 qmails    16   0  1668  508  408 S    0  0.0   2:18.86 qmail-send         
1168 qmaill    18   0  1624  476  404 S    0  0.0   0:22.15 splogger           
1169 root      15   0  1652  388  292 S    0  0.0   0:02.71 qmail-lspawn       
1170 qmailr    15   0  1648  392  296 S    0  0.0   0:11.59 qmail-rspawn       
1171 qmailq    18   0  1620  356  288 S    0  0.0   0:12.25 qmail-clean        
1292 sw-cp-se  15   0  6448 4208 1460 S    0  0.1   7:39.56 sw-cp-serverd      
1456 root      15   0  2008  832  656 S    0  0.0   0:16.97 cron               
7561 root      16   0 10180 2892 2324 S    0  0.0   0:00.05 sshd               
7563 scirocco  15   0 10180 1648 1064 S    0  0.0   0:00.40 sshd               
7564 scirocco  20   0  4508 1972 1364 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash               
7567 root      18   0  7168 1900 1480 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 su
```

Comment: In mysql you should look at the output of `show processlist;`.

Comment: show output from show variables like 'query%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache'; and SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';

Comment: What's really strange here is "0k buffers, 0k cached". I believe this might be an evaluation error of some sort - could you post the output of `free` (and `sar` while you are at it) as well?

Answer (score 2):

It seems tat your machine waits for the disk (56.7%wa), and you have many free memory and only using 1G. So for me it seems that your mysql don't use caches and this is why it waits for the disk for long time and this rises the server load.

Try to increase the memory for your server especially for caches.

Comment: Please see the cache variables of mysql above. Which one should be increased?

Comment: Try https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried and increased the table cache: "Current table_cache hit rate is 0%, while 100% of your table cache is in use
" The server is fine at the moment, however the table cache is full... So I'm not sure if this is the origin of the problem.

Comment: It seems that the table cache is too small to fit all the tables this is why it is 100% full but with no hit rate.